# Centering a merged column vertically and horizontally

Tags: tables, overleaf

I'm using document class "asme2ej" for the document and have been referring to the AMSE LaTex template (which uses a different class) for creating the tables.
I want to make a table that have merged cells in the first row but struggling to get some of the cells to be centered. The following is the code that I used for creating the table:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{Testing for table with merged cells}%
\centering{%
\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\hspace*{1.5em}}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c!{\hspace*{0.5em}}cccccc@{\hspace*{1.5em}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rule{0pt}{8pt}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Category} \\ \cline{2-7} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Type} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X0} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X3} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X4} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X5} \\ \midrule
T1 & 1.0 & 1.0 & & & &  \\
T2 & 1.0 & 1.0 & & & &  \\
T3 & 1.0 & 1.0 & & & &  \\
T4 & 1.0 & 1.0 & & & &  \\
T5 & 1.0 & 1.0 & & & &  \\
T6 & 1.0 & 1.0 & & & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}%
\label{tab:test}
\end{table*}
```

However, this results in the table shown below:
[image]

I want to make "Type" in the center in the vertical direction (it is currently in the bottom of the first row) and "Category" to be in the center of the 6 merged cells.

In addition, it seems that the spacing between the columns are not equal. I'm assuming that it has to do with the first line of code defining the options. I was wondering how I should change them to have equal spacing.

Finally, as I mentioned in the previous question, what are the functions of the tabular options in the very first line of the code:

```
\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\hspace*{1.5em}}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c!{\hspace*{0.5em}}cccccc@{\hspace*{1.5em}}}
```

I was trying things I kind of figured out that the "c" represent the columns but could not find what the other options do.

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated, but most of the `\multicolumn` commands are unnecessary as far as I can tell from a first glance.